# swipe down reload in android studio Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to add a swipe down reload to my app in Kotlin. So to do this, as usual, I followed a tutorial. But I'm getting the error: `Unresolved reference: setOnRefreshListener` and `Unresolved reference: isRefreshing` Here is my code:

MainActivity.kt:

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        refreshApp()
        webViewSetup()
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private fun webViewSetup() {
        val wb_webView = findViewById<View>(R.id.wb_webView) as WebView
        wb_webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        wb_webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        wb_webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        wb_webView.loadUrl("https://google.com/")
    }

    private fun refreshApp() {
        val swipeToRefresh = findViewById<View>(R.id.swipeToRefresh)
        swipeToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
            swipeToRefresh.isRefreshing = false
        }

    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val wb_webView = findViewById<View>(R.id.wb_webView) as WebView
        if (wb_webView.canGoBack()) {
            wb_webView.goBack()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wb_webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I have this in my build.gradle in the dependencies: `implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"`

Does somebody know what my problem is?

Comment: val swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(R.id.swipeToRefresh)

Comment: Add this line instead of yours

Comment: This does get rid of the two errors, but now I'm getting this error: `Unresolved reference: SwipeRefreshLayout`

Comment: import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

Add this

Comment: @Sarah I get no errors now! Do you know if there is a way to test if it actually reloads the page?

Comment: It won't refresh on it's own. You will need to add the refresh code. From code I believe you want to reload the webview? You can add this line inside setOnRefreshListener

**wb_webView.loadUrl("https://google.com/")**
Make sure you have initialized wb_webView at the right place

Comment: @Sarah I'm actually loading a different url and just put google.com for the sake of privacy. But on my website, you go to different places e.g: mywebsitename/login. so if I were to load  wb_webView.loadUrl("mywebsitename") then it will just go to the home page.

Comment: Okay, I don't understand what you want here? If you put in your url in the load method, that will work

Comment: It's fine, I guess this question is unrelated to my origanal question. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
val swipeToRefresh = findViewById<View>(R.id.swipeToRefresh)
```

to this line

```
val swipeToRefresh = findViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(R.id.swipeToRefresh)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. This does get rid of the two errors, but then I get the error: `Unresolved reference: SwipeRefreshLayout`

Comment: @Amy Did you import the `SwipeRefreshLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
```

add this dependency in gradle for swipe refresh